# Remove specific values out of string in cobol

Tags: cobol

Would like to ask how to remove specific values in different lengths out of a string.

I have this:
'{4:72:SELLS¬#:73:ABC¬#:PPF:TESTPPF¬#:74:BLA¬#:PPF:ABC¬#:74:BLA¬#-}'

( want to remove all **¬#:PPF:** Tags with its content. In my example this should be removed:

- **¬#:PPF:TESTPPF**
- **¬#:PPF:ABC** )

And would like to have this:
'{4:72:SELLS¬#:73:ABC¬#:74:BLA¬#:74:BLA¬#-}'

I have this code:

```
01 TINP.
    05 TINPFIELD                         PIC  X(2000) VALUE
       '{4:72:SELLS¬#:73:ABC¬#:PPF:TESTPPF¬#:74:BLA¬#:PPF:TESTPPF¬#:74:BLA¬#-}'.

01 WA-OUTPUT    PIC X(2000) value spaces.
01 WA-TEMP      PIC X(2500).
01 WP-MSG       PIC 9(8) BINARY value zero.
01 WN-ROWCNT    PIC S9(8) BINARY.
01 WN-ROWCNT2   PIC S9(8) BINARY.
01 WP-BEG       PIC 9(8) BINARY.
01 WP-END       PIC 9(8) BINARY.
01 WN-OUT-LEN   PIC 9(8) BINARY value zero.

0000-TESTPROCESSING SECTION.

    display TINPFIELD.

    INSPECT TINPFIELD
            TALLYING WN-Rowcnt FOR ALL "¬#".

    MOVE 1 TO WP-MSG

    PERFORM UNTIL WN-ROWCNT2 >= WN-ROWCNT

      MOVE WP-MSG TO WP-BEG
      display 'WP-BEG' WP-BEG

      UNSTRING TINPFIELD
        DELIMITED BY "¬#"
        INTO WA-TEMP
        POINTER WP-MSG
      END-UNSTRING

      MOVE WP-MSG TO WP-END
      display 'WP-END' WP-END

      if WA-OUTPUT = space
        subtract 1 from wp-end
        STRING TINPFIELD(WP-BEG:WP-END)
               delimited by SIZE
               INTO WA-OUTPUT
        END-STRING
        move wp-end to WN-OUT-LEN
       else
         STRING WA-OUTPUT(1:WN-OUT-LEN)
                delimited by SIZE
                TINPFIELD(WP-BEG:WP-END)
                delimited by SIZE
                '¬#'
                delimited by SIZE
                INTO WA-OUTPUT
         END-STRING
       end-if

       move WP-END TO WN-OUT-LEN
       display 'WN-OUT-LEN' WN-OUT-LEN

       ADD 1 TO WN-ROWCNT2

     END-Perform
     .
     EXIT.
```

//edit: The Input data is always the same. In the output (after my code runs) I have sometimes a "Tag" twice, sometimes only once and so on. Its not consistent at all. I suppose this is a code issue on my side.

Comment: if there is nothing consistent about the data, there is no reliable way to parse it. it might help to understand exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: REPLACING won't do the trick?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto INSPECT REPLACING, will only replace the same number of characters with a string the same size in length

Comment: @SaggingRufus Sorry my wording was not so good. Ive edited the last "chapter" with the input you were mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was changed to reflect a change in the question.

This code splits the input into delimited segments copying each segment directly to the output using reference modification. If there is no text to be removed (no delimiter) it will copy all the input directly to the output.

There are performance implications with this method. Specifically, the move of each segment will cause space-filling in the output. The larger the number of segments the worse the performance.

I changed `WA-OUTPUT` to `X(2000)`, since the output can never be larger than the input.

```
   01 TINP.
       05 TINPFIELD                         PIC  X(2000) VALUE
           '{4:72:SELLS¬#:73:ABC¬#:PPF:TESTPPF¬#:74:BLA' &
           '¬#:PPF:TESTPPF¬#:74:BLA¬#-}'.

   01 WA-OUTPUT    PIC X(2000) value spaces.
   01 segment-length binary pic 9(4).
   01 additional-characters binary pic 9(4).
   01 input-pointer binary pic 9(4).
   01 output-pointer binary pic 9(4).
   01 input-length binary pic 9(4).
   01 output-length binary pic 9(4).
   procedure division.
   begin.
       move 1 to input-pointer output-pointer
                 input-length output-length
       inspect TINPFIELD tallying
           input-length for characters before "}".
       display input-length
       display TINPFIELD
       perform until input-pointer > function length(TINPFIELD)
           unstring TINPFIELD delimited "¬#:PPF:"
               into WA-OUTPUT (output-pointer:)
               count in segment-length
               with pointer input-pointer
           add segment-length to output-pointer
           if input-pointer <= function length(TINPFIELD)
               move 0 to additional-characters
               inspect TINPFIELD (input-pointer:) tallying
                   additional-characters for characters before "¬"
               add additional-characters to input-pointer
           end-if
       end-perform
       inspect WA-OUTPUT tallying
           output-length for characters before "}".
       display wa-output
       display output-length
       goback
       .
```

Output:

```
0070
{4:72:SELLS¬#:73:ABC¬#:PPF:TESTPPF¬#:74:BLA¬#:PPF:TESTPPF¬#:74:BLA¬#-}
{4:72:SELLS¬#:73:ABC¬#:74:BLA¬#:74:BLA¬#-}
0042
```

---

This is a modification of the above that, while slightly more complicated, eliminates the performance penalty for space-filling when there is a larger number of segments. It is unusual because, while it uses the `UNSTRING` statement, it does not actually "unstring" anything.

```
   01 TINP.
       05 TINPFIELD                         PIC  X(2000) VALUE
           '{4:72:SELLS¬#:73:ABC¬#:PPF:TESTPPF¬#:74:BLA' &
           '¬#:PPF:TESTPPF¬#:74:BLA¬#-}'.

   01 WA-OUTPUT    PIC X(2000) value spaces.
   01 segment-length binary pic 9(4).
   01 segment-holder pic x.
   01 additional-characters binary pic 9(4).
   01 input-pointer binary pic 9(4).
   01 backup-pointer binary pic 9(4).
   01 output-pointer binary pic 9(4).
   01 input-length binary pic 9(4).
   01 output-length binary pic 9(4).
   procedure division.
   begin.
       move 1 to input-pointer output-pointer
                 input-length output-length
       inspect TINPFIELD tallying
           input-length for characters before "}".
       display input-length
       display TINPFIELD
       perform until input-pointer > function length(TINPFIELD)
           move input-pointer to backup-pointer
           unstring TINPFIELD delimited "¬#:PPF:"
               into segment-holder
               count in segment-length
               with pointer input-pointer
           move TINPFIELD (backup-pointer:segment-length)
               to WA-OUTPUT (output-pointer:segment-length)
           add segment-length to output-pointer
           if input-pointer <= function length(TINPFIELD)
               move 0 to additional-characters
               inspect TINPFIELD (input-pointer:) tallying
                   additional-characters for characters before "¬"
               add additional-characters to input-pointer
           end-if
       end-perform
       if output-pointer < function length (WA-OUTPUT)
           move space to WA-OUTPUT (output-pointer:)
       inspect WA-OUTPUT tallying
           output-length for characters before "}".
       display wa-output
       display output-length
       goback
       .
```

The output is the same.

Comment: the ** are bold formatting characters which didnt affect, sorry for that. Ive tried your first example, works perfectly fine. Thanks for that. One Additional question for the first example you've provided: Is there a way to extract the PPF tag-values with different lengths? eg. once its like "¬#:PPF:TESTPPF" and once its like "¬#:PPF:TEST", "¬#:PPF:ABC" and so on...

Comment: @vogt - Yes, `delimited  "¬#:PPF:TESTPPF" or "¬#:PPF:TEST" or "¬#:PPF:ABC" or ...`. Just be certain the delimiters occur in an order that avoids the partial removal of the longer delimiter.

Comment: @vogt - Note that the code was changed to reflect the change in the question.